# Is it safe to save passwords on Microsoft or Vivaldi servers?

Tags: security, passwords, windows-11, microsoft-edge

Every couple of months, I read in the news that Microsoft servers get hacked. It seems like that has been a routine for Microsoft (I hear less so about Google or Apple getting compromised). Now that Microsoft is aggressively pushing Edge browser. I'm tempted to stop using Chrome and give Edge or Vivaldi a try. I have in the past stored my passwords on Google's server through Chrome. Third party browser like Vivaldi also allows users to create an account with them, and sync passwords to that account.

I've read that some companies save passwords in an encrypted format. So even if someone were to obtain a physical copy of the passwords, they would not be able to read the saved passwords. I wonder if Microsoft or Vivaldi does that. Is it safe for me to save my passwords on their servers?

Comment: You can store your passwords within a browser and NOT synchronize them to Microsoft if you do desire. Microsoft hasn’t announced a single compromise that deal with data stored within a user’s Microsoft Account

Comment: Yes, don't use the Sync feature and [Edge will only store passwords encrypted on your local disk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-security-password-manager-security).

Comment: I'm hoping to store them remotely

Comment: @jeffrey - But you don’t trust Microsoft not to get hacked.  So you have to give up something, or use a third-party password service, that store’s password differently

Comment: Why not use a KDB database (eg Keypass), integrate it with your preferred browser and sync the encrypted DB to the cloud?